Problemas instalando IDE Eclipse
tengo problemas instalando el IDE Eclipse para JAVA desde www.eclipse.org. Resulta que descargo el software, ejecuto la instalación y el IDE se ejecuta sin problemas... pero una vez que lo cierro me doy cuenta de que nunca se instaló. Al hacer clic en el icono del escritorio del IDE Eclipse no abre nunca, reviso en las aplicaciones de Win10 que tengo instalada y no aparece Eclipse... es como si nunca se hubiera instalado.
Para volver a trabajar con este IDE tengo que volver a instalarlo cada vez ¿qué estará pasando?

Hola Felipe, bienvenido, cuando dices "ejecuto la instalación y el IDE se ejecuta sin problemas", realmente hace una instalación, o le das al ".exe" y arranca el programa?, porque de ser así, puede que hallas bajado un programa que no requiere instalación, y solo debes agregar una entrada en el lanzador de aplicaciones.

Hola Marce. Gracias por la bienvenida. Mira realmente bajé un instalador (.exe) donde se ve la interfaz de instalación del software, me pide escoger qué versión de Eclipse instalar... descarga los paquetes y realiza el proceso de instalación, después crea un acceso directo en el escritorio de la aplicación y ejecuta Eclipse. Empiezo a usar Eclipse y al cerrarlo me doy cuenta de que nunca instaló nada y que el acceso directo en el escritorio no hace nada de nada. Por eso mi consulta. Bajé el instalador de la web oficial de Eclipse (www.eclipse.org).
